# Add title to meta analysis forest plot

Tags: r

I am meta-analysing some studies and drawing a forest plot for my results. However I can`t seem to get the forest plot to display the title.

An example of my code is:

```
require(meta)
parameter1<-metaprop(sm="PLOGIT", 
                 event=c(4,16,3,2,10,1,0,2), 
                 n=c(90,402,89,29,153,86,21,48), 
                 level = 0.95, 
                 studlab=c("study 1",
                           "study 2",
                           "study 3",
                           "study 4",
                           "study 5",
                           "study 6",
                           "study 7",
                           "study 8"), 
                 title="meta analysis 1")
forest(parameter1)
```

When it produces the forest plot, the title "meta analysis 1" is missing.

How can I add this in?

Thanks in advance,

Timothy

Comment: I suspect the argument is called `,main` not `,title`.

Comment: That seems to give the following error though "unused argument(s) (main = "meta analysis 1")"

Comment: also using `complab=` or `outclab=` doesn`t work either.

Comment: @Backlin points out that forest is based on grid not base graphics, so I wouldn't expect `main` to work, sorry.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems to me the `forest` function does not have any obvious way of plotting a title. But do not despair, `forest` uses grid graphics, and we can easily add the title manually like this.

```
grid.text("My custom title", .5, .9, gp=gpar(cex=2))
```

See `?gpar` for how to style the text.

Comment: thank you! Works great. One question with it, the title appears quite high above the chart, is there a way to change the distance between the title and the chart? I could not see it with `?gpar`? Many thanks!

Comment: `.9` is the y position of the title, so just use a smaller value to move it further down. For reference, `0` is at the lower edge of the plot and `1` is at the upper.