# Reproduce table and plot from journal

Tags: r, plot

I am a surgeon and love coding.
I do my best to fit R's coding for my papers, but have problem with table creation. 
I found and table and plot combination in famous journal (NEJM) and it look like this:

[image]

How can I reproduce this kind of table and forest plot combination in **R**?

Comment: Have you tried `meta` package? For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372230/add-title-to-meta-analysis-forest-plot

Comment: That's a lot of insignificant p-values for a published article in the New England Journal of Significant Results :)

Comment: @rawr True fact. Ignoring insignificant results does introduce bias to our body of knowledge though!

Comment: Can you link to the original paper, ideally to the PDF? Maybe you could find out which tool they use for the typeset.

Comment: Here is the [article](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa1301228). I'm not sure about the rules for posting a PDF from an article that I don't own, so I'll leave just the link. It would be nice to have the data to play with, but that probably won't happen any time soon. Confidentiality etc.

Comment: @rawr and none of them significant! Maybe they're trying to prove the null exhaustively :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**nevermind: it was done with the meta package**

The amount of work involved will be significantly influenced by whether or not you want R code to produce that entire page of information, or want to use R to create the graph in the middle and add it to a document (MSWord, etc.) that contains the text info. If the latter approach is ok, then start with a horizontal bar plot (e.g., http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_boxplot.html), use something like theme_classic() to clear background, and use xlim() to scale the x-axis. If you revise your question and add a text representation of an actual data frame (e.g., like in this post: [date at which a percentage of maximum was surpassed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420860/date-at-which-a-percentage-of-maximum-was-surpassed)), me or someone else would probably generate the ggplot code for you.

Answer (score 36):

How about this, with `ggplot2` and `grid`:

I plotted it as 2 panels because the log scale needed for the boxplot doesn't let you plot 'negatives' i.e. labels and data to the left of the zero value.

It should scale OK (you can change the font sizes in the top block of code) and also you can add "whitespace" lines under the text by increasing the `blankRows` variable if there's not enough data for a page.

The csv for the group format is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B85i6kIzoV0oSm9PZFNEYUV1WkE/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

As requested, to use 95% CI bars instead, add this above the plot calls to show format:

```
## MOCK up confidence interval data in the form:
## ID (level from groupData), low (2.5%) high (97.5%), target
CI_Data<-ddply(hazardData[!is.na(hazardData$HR),],.(ID),summarize,low=min(HR),high=max(HR),target=mean(HR))
```

Replace:

```
  geom_boxplot(fill=boxColor,size=0.5, alpha=0.8, notch=F)
```

With:

```
  geom_point(data=CI_Data,aes(x = factor(ID), y = target),shape=22,size=5,fill=boxColor,vjust=0) + 
  geom_errorbar(data=CI_Data,aes(x=factor(ID),y=target,ymin =low, ymax=high),width=0.5)+
```

[image]

```
## REQUIRED PACKAGES
require(grid)
require(ggplot2)
require(plyr)

############################################
### CUSTOMIZE APPEARANCE WITH THESE     ####
############################################
blankRows<-2    # blank rows under boxplot
titleSize<-4
dataSize<-4
boxColor<-"pink"
############################################
############################################

## BASIC THEMES (SO TO PLOT BLANK GRID)
theme_grid <- theme(
  axis.line = element_blank(), 
  axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
  axis.text.y = element_blank(),
  axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
  axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
  axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
  axis.ticks.length = unit(0.0001, "mm"),
  axis.ticks.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "lines"), 
  legend.position = "none", 
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"), 
  panel.border = element_blank(), 
  panel.grid.major = element_line(colour="grey"), 
  panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour="grey"), 
  panel.margin = unit(c(-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1), "mm"), 
  plot.margin = unit(c(5,0,5,0.01), "mm")
)

theme_bare <- theme_grid +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  )

## LOAD GROUP DATA AND P values from csv file
groupData<-read.csv(file="groupdata.csv",header=T)

## SYNTHESIZE SOME PLOT DATA - you can load csv instead
## EXPECTS 2 columns - integer for 'ID' matching groupdatacsv
## AND 'HR' Hazard Rate
hazardData<-expand.grid(ID=1:nrow(groupData),HR=1:6)
hazardData$HR<-1.3-runif(nrow(hazardData))*0.7
hazardData<-rbind(hazardData,ddply(groupData,.(Group),summarize,ID=max(ID)+0.1,HR=NA)[,2:3])
hazardData<-rbind(hazardData,data.frame(ID=c(0,-1:(-2-blankRows),max(groupData$ID)+1,max(groupData$ID)+2),HR=NA))

## Make the min/max mean labels
hrlabels<-ddply(hazardData[!is.na(hazardData$HR),],.(ID),summarize,lab=paste(round(mean(HR),2)," (",round(min(HR),2),"-",round(max(HR),2),")",sep=""))

## Points to plot on the log scale
scaledata<-data.frame(ID=0,HR=c(0.2,0.6,0.8,1.2,1.8))

## Pull out the Groups & P values
group_p<-ddply(groupData,.(Group),summarize,P=mean(P_G),y=max(ID)+0.1)

## identify the rows to be highlighted, and 
## build a function to add the layers
hl_rows<-data.frame(ID=(1:floor(length(unique(hazardData$ID[which(hazardData$ID>0)]))/2))*2,col="lightgrey")
hl_rows$ID<-hl_rows$ID+blankRows+1
hl_rect<-function(col="white",alpha=0.5){
  rectGrob(   x = 0, y = 0, width = 1, height = 1, just = c("left","bottom"), gp=gpar(alpha=alpha, fill=col))
}

## DATA FOR TEXT LABELS
RtLabels<-data.frame(x=c(rep(length(unique(hazardData$ID))-0.2,times=3)),
                      y=c(0.6,6,10),
                      lab=c("Hazard Ratio\n(95% CI)","P Value","P Value for\nInteraction"))

LfLabels<-data.frame(x=c(rep(length(unique(hazardData$ID))-0.2,times=2)),
                     y=c(0.5,4),
                     lab=c("Subgroup","No. of\nPatients"))

LegendLabels<-data.frame(x=c(rep(1,times=2)),
                     y=c(0.5,1.8),
                     lab=c("Off-Pump CABG Better","On-Pump CABG Better"))

## BASIC PLOT
haz<-ggplot(hazardData,aes(factor(ID),HR))+ labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)

## RIGHT PANEL WITH LOG SCALE
rightPanel<-haz + 
  apply(hl_rows,1,function(x)annotation_custom(hl_rect(x["col"],alpha=0.4),as.numeric(x["ID"])-0.5,as.numeric(x["ID"])+0.5,-20,20)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2, y = 1, xend = 1.5, yend = 1)) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=1),linetype=2, size=0.5)+
  geom_boxplot(fill=boxColor,size=0.5, alpha=0.8)+ 
  scale_y_log10() + coord_flip() +
  geom_text(data=scaledata,aes(3,HR,label=HR), vjust=0.5, size=dataSize) +
  geom_text(data=RtLabels,aes(x,y,label=lab, fontface="bold"), vjust=0.5, size=titleSize) +
  geom_text(data=hrlabels,aes(factor(ID),4,label=lab),vjust=0.5, hjust=1, size=dataSize) +
  geom_text(data=group_p,aes(factor(y),11,label=P, fontface="bold"),vjust=0.5, hjust=1, size=dataSize) +
  geom_text(data=groupData,aes(factor(ID),6.5,label=P_S),vjust=0.5, hjust=1, size=dataSize) +
  geom_text(data=LegendLabels,aes(x,y,label=lab, fontface="bold"),hjust=0.5, vjust=1, size=titleSize) +
  geom_point(data=scaledata,aes(2.5,HR),shape=3,size=3) + 
  geom_point(aes(2,12),shape=3,alpha=0,vjust=0) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2.5, y = 0, xend = 2.5, yend = 13)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2, y = 1, xend = 2, yend = 1.8),arrow=arrow(),linetype=1,size=1) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2, y = 1, xend = 2, yend = 0.2),arrow=arrow(),linetype=1,size=1) + 
  theme_bare

## LEFT PANEL WITH NORMAL SCALE
leftPanel<-haz + 
  apply(hl_rows,1,function(x)annotation_custom(hl_rect(x["col"],alpha=0.4),as.numeric(x["ID"])-0.5,as.numeric(x["ID"])+0.5,-20,20)) +
  coord_flip(ylim=c(0,5.5)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=factor(ID),y=1),shape=3,alpha=0,vjust=0) + 
  geom_text(data=group_p,aes(factor(y),0.5,label=Group, fontface="bold"),vjust=0.5, hjust=0, size=dataSize) +
  geom_text(data=groupData,aes(factor(ID),1,label=Subgroup),vjust=0.5, hjust=0, size=dataSize) +
  geom_text(data=groupData,aes(factor(ID),5,label=NoP),vjust=0.5, hjust=1, size=dataSize) +
  geom_text(data=LfLabels,aes(x,y,label=lab, fontface="bold"), vjust=0.5, hjust=0, size=4, size=titleSize) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2.5, y = 0, xend = 2.5, yend = 5.5)) + 
  theme_bare

## PLOT THEM BOTH IN A GRID SO THEY MATCH UP
grid.arrange(leftPanel,rightPanel, widths=c(1,3), ncol=2, nrow=1)
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for contribution. Quick question: What do the ranges of the box plot refer to? And whiskers? I think the standard in this kind of graphs is to plot point estimate and 95% CI..

Comment: I think the default for geom_boxplot() is that the boxes are the 25th-75th percentiles, and the whisker goes to furthest point within 1.5 * IQR either way. I used these because I think they can be most easily transformed to show info about the data range using the stat transformation. Also if you set notch=T in the geom_boxplot() call, it will move the hinges to 1.58 * IQR / sqrt(n) which is apparently an approximation for 95% CI.

Comment: But of course you can easily change the geom_boxplot() call to show any combination of line/point/area

Comment: OK - updated to show how to display it in the standard format

Comment: I am getting error messages, I think the code needs to be updated due to changes in plyr

Comment: @Troy Thx for this giant effort. I tried the same code but I am getting errors as `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Subgroup' not found` and ``` Duplicated aesthetics after name standardisation: size ``` Thx

Comment: This solution seems really nice. Do you still happen to have the csv file for the group format? The link didn't work anymore.

Answer (score 32):

The challenge with these kinds of plots is not the plotting (you simply need to build in all the right text and line functions). Instead it is getting the data in the right format. For this kind of plot, I would treat each row as an observation in a dataframe and make each column the relevant piece of information that you want place on the plot.

Here's an example for just the first few rows of your image and then the long set of plotting commands necessary to make it happen. They're basically all vectorized, though, so adding rows to the dataframe only requires modifying a few parameters.

Here's the data:

```
mydf <- data.frame(
    SubgroupH=c('Age',NA,NA,'Sex',NA,NA),
    Subgroup=c(NA,'<70','>70',NA,'Male','Female'),
    NoOfPatients=c(NA,2815,1935,NA,3843,908),
    HazardRatio=c(NA,0.97,0.86,NA,0.93,0.81),
    HazardLower=c(NA,0.77,0.69,NA,0.78,0.59),
    HazardUpper=c(NA,1.22,1.07,NA,1.12,1.12),
    Pvalue=c(NA,0.77,0.17,NA,0.47,0.21),
    PvalueI=c(0.46,NA,NA,0.46,NA,NA),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
```

And here's the plot:

```
#png('temp.png', width=8, height=4, units='in', res=400)
rowseq <- seq(nrow(mydf),1)
par(mai=c(1,0,0,0))
plot(mydf$HazardRatio, rowseq, pch=15,
    xlim=c(-10,12), ylim=c(0,7),
    xlab='', ylab='', yaxt='n', xaxt='n',
    bty='n')
axis(1, seq(-2,2,by=.4), cex.axis=.5)

segments(1,-1,1,6.25, lty=3)
segments(mydf$HazardLower, rowseq, mydf$HazardUpper, rowseq)

mtext('Off-Pump\nCABG Better',1, line=2.5, at=0, cex=.5, font=2)
mtext('On-Pump\nCABG Better',1.5, line=2.5, at=2, cex=.5, font=2)

text(-8,6.5, "Subgroup", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t1h <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$SubgroupH), mydf$SubgroupH, '')
text(-8,rowseq, t1h, cex=.75, pos=4, font=3)
t1 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$Subgroup), mydf$Subgroup, '')
text(-7.5,rowseq, t1, cex=.75, pos=4)

text(-5,6.5, "No. of\nPatients", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t2 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$NoOfPatients), format(mydf$NoOfPatients,big.mark=","), '')
text(-3, rowseq, t2, cex=.75, pos=2)

text(-1,6.5, "Hazard Ratio (95%)", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t3 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$HazardRatio), with(mydf, paste(HazardRatio,' (',HazardLower,'-',HazardUpper,')',sep='')), '')
text(3,rowseq, t3, cex=.75, pos=4)

text(7.5,6.5, "P Value", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t4 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$Pvalue), mydf$Pvalue, '')
text(7.5,rowseq, t4, cex=.75, pos=4)

text(10,6.5, "P Value for\nInteraction", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t5 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$PvalueI), mydf$PvalueI, '')
text(10,rowseq, t5, cex=.75, pos=4)
#dev.off()
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Great job! Looks really good already. Quick question. Is there a way to control the vertical space left between the'rows'? The reason I'm asking is that sometimes this kind of displays can get very large, like the one OP posted in the question.

Comment: @radek Yes, I've set it up to place all of the rows at equal spacings of 1 unit (see the `rowseq` variable), but this could be changed to anything. Note also that the appearance of that spacing is going to depend on the aspect ratio and resolution of the final image (and what graphics device is used). The above example is PNG but it might look different on a different device.

Comment: Great. Thanks for quick answer. Will give it a shot with my data then.

Comment: Quick question - is it possible to align column with number of patients to the right and introduce comma separator for thousands? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also followed up with question on grey shaded boxes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356019/in-base-r-graphics-is-it-possible-to-find-exact-placing-of-the-added-rectangles

Answer (score 18):

The [sparkTable package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sparkTable/index.html) can do this. For example:

```
install.packages("sparkTable", dep=TRUE)
library(sparkTable)
## Example creates a bunch of files, so run it in a new folder
dir.create("tempDir")
setwd("tempDir")
example(plotSparkTable)
setwd("..")
```

and running `pdflatex` on the resulting t2.tex file produces the graphic below.
 [image: plotSparktable example]