# date at which a percentage of maximum was surpassed

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like following:

```
df <- data.frame(site=paste0('site', sort(rep(1:5, 20))),
                 date=as.Date(paste0(sample(1:28, 100, replace=T), '/', 
                                     sample(1:12, 100, replace=T), '/', 
                                     2013), 
                              '%d/%m/%Y'), 
                 count=rep(seq(1, 1000, length.out=20), 10))
```

For each site, I need the earliest date in time `count` > 500. In in other words, the first date at which the count was >50% of max count.

Comment: Do you want the first date as it appears in your data, or the first date in time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solutions with `plyr`.

If you want the first date where count > 500 :

```
ddply(df, .(site), summarise, date=min(date[count>500]))
```

If you want the first date where count > 50%*max(count) (for each site) :

```
ddply(df, .(site), summarise, date=min(date[count>max(count)*0.5]))
```

Here both give the same result :

```
   site       date
1 site1 2013-01-15
2 site2 2013-02-04
3 site3 2013-03-13
4 site4 2013-02-04
5 site5 2013-01-07
```