# In base R graphics, is it possible to find exact placing of the added rectangles?

Tags: r, graphics, transparency

Following up this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420621/reproduce-table-and-plot-from-journal) on an attempt to reproduce the complex graph I am working with [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2338862/thomas)' [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420621/reproduce-table-and-plot-from-journal/20144999#20144999).

All works exactly as specified but I was wondering if there is an option to add transparent grey shading to alternate 'rows' of the graph, similarly as it is done in the original version provided by OP.

Digging around I've found an option to add transparent rectangle covering specified area, for instance:

```
rect(-10, 2.8, 12, 3.3, col="#00000025", border=NA)
```

However - the upper and lower limits have to be chosen (with patience ;) largely by trial and error.

Is there a way to add some automation to this process?

Comment: You might try just doing a series of `abline`s (use the `h` argument) with a very thick `lwd` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on your solution:

```
shaded_rowseq <- rowseq[rep(c(T,F),length(rowseq)/2)]
rect(-10, shaded_rowseq-0.5, 12, shaded_rowseq+0.5, col="#00000025", border=NA)
```