# Forest plot from cox object

Tags: r, plot

Please be tolerant :) I am a dummy user of R and I am using the code and sample data to learn how to make forest plot that was shown in the previous post -

[Optimal/efficient plotting of survival/regression analysis results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289111/optimal-efficient-plotting-of-survival-regression-analysis-results/31373382#31373382)

I was wondering is it possible to set user-defined x-axis scale with the code shown there? Up to now x a-axis scale is defined somehow automatically.
Thank you for any tips.

Comment: Short answer: "of course it's possible". How do you want ti changed? Have you done any searching on SO for tweaks to ggplot axes along the lines of what you are requesting?

Comment: @42 Basically, i want to find where in this code i can change x-axis scale, so that, for example, I would set it in the range between 0 and 50. I have looked ggplot2 and tried to do it, but after that code didn't work at all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unimpressed with the precision of the documentation since one might assume that the `limits` argument would be values on the relative risk scale rather than on the log-transformed scale. One gets a ridiculous result if that is done. That quibble not withstanding, it's relatively easy to use that parameter to created an expanded plot:

```
install('devtools')   # then use it to get current package
# executing the install and load of the package referenced at the top of that answer
print(forest_model(lung_cox, limits=log( c(.5, 50) ) ))
```

[image]

Trying for a lower range of 0 on the relative risk scale is not sensible. Would imply a -Inf value on hte log-transformed scale. Trying for lower value, say log(0.001), confuses the pretty printing of the scale in my tests.

Comment: Thank you. However, I'm afraid the code you proposed returns an error `unused argument (limits = log(c(0.5, 50)))`. I could suggest that it is because `limits` are not used in above mentioned code?

Comment: You probably don't have a current version of the package. Since I just installed it today from github, and then rebooted R to let the ggplot2 update take effect, I'm reasonably confident that I do.