# Improve Forest plot for subgroup analysis (not for meta-analysis)?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, r-forestplot

Currently my forest plots for subgroup analysis (not for meta-analysis) in R are like the following...

```
library("dplyr")
library(ggplot2)
library(survminer)
library(survival)
library(forestmodel)

pretty_lung <- lung %>%
  transmute(time,
            status,
            Age = age,
            Sex = factor(sex, labels = c("Male", "Female")),
            ECOG = factor(lung$ph.ecog),
            `Meal Cal` = meal.cal)

print(forest_model(coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ ., pretty_lung)))
```

[image: forstplot]

However, the sizes/heights of the squares are not proportional to the subgroup sample size. In other words, I would expect that the smaller the confidence interval, the larger the boxes/squares would be.
Is there a way to fix that (as in this example: https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(05)61026-4/fulltext)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some time I've found a decent solution (using another package):

```
devtools::install_github("ewenharrison/finalfit")
library(finalfit)
library(dplyr) 
library(ggplot2)
library(survminer)
library(survival)

pretty_lung <- lung %>%
  transmute(time,
            status,
            Age = age,
            Sex = factor(sex, labels = c("Male", "Female")),
            ECOG = factor(lung$ph.ecog),
            `Meal Cal` = meal.cal)

explanatory = c("Age", "Sex", "ECOG", "`Meal Cal`")
dependent = "Surv(time, status)"
pretty_lung %>%
  hr_plot(dependent, explanatory, dependent_label = "Survival")
```

The output:

[image]

It may not be perfect, but it is another option and this package does the job with the sizes/heights of the squares