# Creating "Zebra" format in ggplot or sjplot forest plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

Is there a way to make a forest plot have alternating translucent grey and white boxes for each variable in a forest plot in `ggplot` or `sjplot` similar to this formatting (preferably for `sjplot`)? I'd ideally like to do this using only a model object provided as the input and then the set the zebra theme

It's basically just the zebra format from the r package `table1` seen in this link [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html)

[image: picture].

Comment: I would suggest to read your solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20266137/3519756)

Comment: my question is more theme specific. I don't care about anything other than theme, which isn't really touched on in that answer. Someone does seem to get what I'm looking for, but their answer doesn't appear to scale when you don't have the table of the subgroups ready to go. Ideally this is just something available in the `plot_model` part of `sjplot` but I cannot find it