# Reproduce table and plot showing Odds Ratio per group and displaying estimates by the plot' side

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am not good with ggplot2 despite being such a fantastic library. I found in a paper a combination of plot and table that I would like to reproduce, but I am struggling. The figure looks like this:

[image]

How can I reproduce this forest plot by the side of its groups' respective estimates and according to different outcome variables?

Comment: In short, it's a little complicated but [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20266137/10744082) [exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62312135/10744082). You have to plot a pretend table using `geom_texts` to line up alongside the forest plot.