# How to set zero as the first x-axis tick mark of an odds ratio forestplot in package metafor?

Tags: r, metafor

In package metafor, consider the code below for a forest plot of odds ratios:

```
res = rma(measure = "OR", ai = TP, bi =  FP, ci = FN, di = TN, data = data1, method="PM") 
forest(res, atransf = exp)
```

Now how can I set the first position of the
x-axis tick marks to 0? I know I should use `atransf = exp` for plotting
odds ratios and also `at = log(b)` where `b` is a vector of values. I just
don't know which number should be set as the first element of `b`, so that
it gives back 0 as the first tick mark for odds ratios.

I also wonder how I can change the default title at the bottom of the
forest plot. In case of odds ratio it is "Odd Ratio (log scale)". I prefer
it to be "Odds Ratio".

Comment: This is for the title: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372230/add-title-to-meta-analysis-forest-plot

Comment: I guess `1` should be the values but it's kinda vague to me what are you asking.

Comment: @Masoud: Since odds ratio is a proportion, the real value never can be 0. Yet I want 0 to be the first tick mark of its axis to be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is impossible. On the log scale, an odds ratio of 0 would have to be an infinite amount of space to the left (try `at=log(c(1e-10,1,5))` to see what happens if you use a number very close to 0). That is obviously not going to work.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I tried this solution and the value 0.5 worked fine for my plot. Now going to my other question: how can I change the default title at the bottom of the plot?

Comment: Use the `xlab` argument.